# After a US B2 visa refusal, do I qualify for ESTA/VWP under my new UK citizenship?

Tags: visa-refusals, esta, b1-b2-visas, uk-citizens, filipino-citizens

I had applied for a US B2 visitor visa in 2014 but I got refused. At that time, I applied with my Philippine passport.

Now, I am a UK citizen and have a British passport. Am I qualified for the ESTA/VWP or should I apply again for a B1 visitor visa?

I am traveling in April but I really don’t know what to do. I am worried I may not qualify for the ESTA.